# updating ng-view without updating url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm studing angularJS and I have situation where I have to load a new view by clicking button, but keep the url same. I have done same with jQuery like this:
    `$(".container").fadeOut("slow").load('page.html').hide().fadeIn();`

How is it possible? I dont want to change/route url, because other view is useless without  visiting the other view/page first. Transitions are necessery.

I was thinking ng-include also. But is it possible to strap it to a specific controller for each included template like it is via router(like below)? Or should i do some custom directive?

```
        .when('/page', {
        controller: Controller,
        templateUrl: 'page.html'
    })
```

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you programmatically change the ng-view using `$location.url(...)`

Comment: I tried, but it brings the path to the address field..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real options if you don't want to change the path are to use ng-include or a custom directive.  The easiest thing to do would be use ng-include.  You can just add a ng-controller to the root element of you included HTML for your controller mapping.

Ng-view only works with routes so a path change would be required to use ng-view.